# Could anyone fix my delete function in jsp and servlet Please

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have already coded the servlet and the dao part of the delete method.
Once i want to use the method in jsp page, it returned ERROR 500 / ERROR 404.

I am using tomcat 7,Java 7 and windows 10. Running oracle. I tried to use ajax to link the servlet delete method but it still didn't work.

```
// deleteStaffServelt
public class DeleteStaffServlet extends HttpServlet {

    enter code here
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String ids = request.getParameter("userId");

        int deleteId = Integer.parseInt(ids);
        StaffDao staffDao = new StaffDao();
        staffDao.delete(deleteId);
        response.sendRedirect("deleteStaffServlet?id=" + deleteId);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

// delete method in Dao
public void delete(int id) {
        try {
            String sql = "delete from ZZZ_EMPLOYEES where ZE_ID = " + id;
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

// jsp
<body>
    <form action="listServletTwo">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>社員No. <input name="noStart" type="text" size="8" />
                    &nbsp;～&nbsp; <input name="noEnd" type="text" size="8" /> <input
                    type="submit" value="検索" />
                </td>
                <td>社員名. <input name="name" type="text" size="20" /> <input
                    type="submit" value="検索" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </br>
        <%
            List<Staff> list1 = (List<Staff>) session.getAttribute("list");
            if (list1 != null) {
        %>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
            <tr bgcolor="pink">
                <td>社員No.</td>
                <td>ユーザーID</td>
                <td>社員名</td>
                <td>削除機能</td>
                <td>更新機能</td>
            </tr>
            <%
                for (Staff s : list1) {
            %>
            <tr>
                <td id="<%=s.getId()%>"><%=s.getId()%></td>
                <td><%=s.getNo()%></td>
                <td><%=s.getName()%></td>
                <td><a href="deleteStaffServlet?id=<%=s.getId()%>" name="userId">Delete</a></td>
                <td>名前:<input name="name" type="text" size="10" /> ユーザーID:<input
                    name="name" type="text" size="10" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit" onclick="editRecord(<%=s.getId()%>);">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <%
                }
                }
                session.removeAttribute("list");
            %>

        </table>
    </form>
```

result is HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Comment: check the value of `ids` in  `int deleteId = Integer.parseInt(ids);`  maybe not an `int`

Comment: Please show the error log.  By default it is in the Tomcat directory under the logs directory.

Comment: @Jason *null pointer exception* - are you sure?

Comment: OP. learn how to use JSTL in your JSP

Comment: Do you realize it 2019, and there can be no reason to write new code using Servlet? None whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Here ,`<a href="deleteStaffServlet?id=<%=s.getId()%>" name="userId">Delete</a>`,you have used  `id=<%=s.getId()%>` i.e : you are getting value `<%=s.getId()%>` in parameter `id` but in your `servlet` ,you are getting parameter using `request.getParameter("userId");` just change this to `request.getParameter("id");`.

Also, your `delete query` is wrong it should like below :

```
// delete method in Dao
public void delete(int id) {
        try {
          //you have to give placeholder(?) in query not the value 
            String sql = "delete from ZZZ_EMPLOYEES where ZE_ID =?";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
     }
```

I am not sure what you are doing here :

```
response.sendRedirect("deleteStaffServlet?id=" + deleteId);
```

But, I think you have already deleted required `row` from table  ,so there is no need to do that again. So, just change that to below :

```
 response.sendRedirect("yourjsppage");
```